# Prove that if sets A and B satisfy this relation, then they have a common element.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

[image]

I have done the proof by drawing the picture and explaining it by using an example, but how could I start a more formal proof for this example without the use of a numeric example?

Comment: Prove the contrapositive. If $A\cap B=\varnothing\ldots$

Comment: Is it helpful to point out that for finite sets, $|A\cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A\cap B|$?

Comment: @MPW: And what if $A$ and $B$ are infinite?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I think my comment only makes sense for finite sets

Comment: @MPW: It is, because subtraction doesn't make sense in the infinite case; which is why your comment is helpful but ultimately not helpful enough.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Yes, agreed. It wasn't clear to me whether the OP intended to consider infinite sets. The proof is considerably easier for finite sets. In fact, I'm not entirely sure that it is true for infinite sets--note the strict inequality.

Comment: @MPW: It is, because we don't require that if the intersection is non-empty, then ...; instead we require that if the union has a strictly smaller cardinality then the intersection is non-empty. The question whether or not this can even happen with infinite sets is a different question altogether (whose answer depends on the axiom of choice).

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I'm not following this. Can you demonstrate a pair of sets, at least one of which is infinite, which satisfies this inequality? I suspect that if $|A|<|B|$ and $B$ is infinite, then $|A\cup B| = |B|$, but I'm not certain of this.

Comment: @MPW: If we assume the AC, then you're right. $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|$ regardless to being disjoint. If we don't assume the axiom of choice then counterexamples are consistent. In either case, if you look at the implication in the question, it begins by stating that $|A\cup B|<|A|+|B|$, whether or not it holds for infinite sets is irrelevant. Not to mention that not everyone talk about the axiom of choice and what it does to cardinal arithmetic at such point (sometimes they don't mention it at all, other times they do later on, and sometimes they do before hand). So we're just grinding water here.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Recall that $|A|+|B|$ is defined to be as $|A'\cup B'|$ such that $|A|=|A'|$ and $|B|=|B'|$ and $A'\cap B'=\varnothing$.

Comment: So use that fact and go with a proof by contrapositive?

Comment: For example, yes.